# Will a site login protect a site from SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

I have secure site with a login before anyone can enter the site and submit any form data. Is this secure enough from SQL injection?

Comment: One has absolutely nothing to do with the other. Any page that uses a query should be checked for injection.

Comment: Nothing is **really** secure in IT.

Comment: Think what you want to do is sanitize all input, remember you should be treating all input as evil.  [link](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: Where is Little Bobby Tables when you need him? http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: things in IT can be secure. Just not bulletproof :)

Comment: If you trust your users (given the initial pwd), and the login can't be hammered, concider it as "an ugly fix but fairly secure."

Comment: Only if you never give the logins to anyone and you rip off your apostrophe keys. Heh.

Comment: @user247245: what does a login has to do with preventing sql injection???

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa and PeeHaa you both are right.

Comment: @peehaa, nothing really. But PDO isn't a silver bullet.

Comment: @user247245 Sure, but I'd rather use a normal lead bullet as ammo in my gun than trying to use a carrot to shoot someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## NO

SQL Injection has nothing to do with authentication; it has to do with the way you sanitize user input. In other words, a user with perfectly good credentials may have bad intention and decide that he'd want to try and drop your database by entering malicious text on some of your form's fields.

On PHP, you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to sanitize your input and form your SQL statements via string concatenation but if you can implement [prepared statements](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) (also known as parametrized queries) much better since your query plans may be reused and you gain a performance boost as well.

Answer (score 1):

NO!

It makes it vulnerable (if not done properly. Well as vulnerable as everything after the login).

Since hackers can use the form to inject sql.

A login != slq injection protection.

Sanitizing user input is.

Use for example:

```
mysql_real_escape_string()

mysqli_real_escape_string()

pdo's prepared statements
```

Answer (score 0):

Not if the user uses sql injection on your logon form. How does the logon form work. If it checks using a select then you still need to strip out bad sql etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your terms its a [Grandfather Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox), say if your login does provide protection to sql injection then on the login page user is not logged in. By the way authorization/authentication and sql injection both are unrelated things, So your answer is **NO**.